# Func NUnit Equality Comparison

Tags: c#, nunit, equality, func

How does Equality comparison work for a `Func`? I have reduced the complexity of my problem to these unit tests:

```
[Test]
public void Will_Pass()
{
    Func<string> func = () => "key";
    Assert.That(func, Is.EqualTo(func));
}

[Test]
public void Will_Fail()
{
    Func<string> funcA = () => "key";
    Func<string> funcB = () => "key";
    Assert.That(funcA, Is.EqualTo(funcB));
}
```

I need to test - and successfully assert - that one instance of a `Func` is equal to another instance. So I basically need a way to make the Failing test pass.

Is there a way to do this without creating a custom type and overriding `Equals()`?

Comment: Perhaps this would be easier with expression trees instead of `Func<T>`.

Comment: See [ExpressionEqualityComparer.cs](https://source.db4o.com/db4o/trunk/db4o.net/Db4objects.Db4o.Linq/Db4objects.Db4o.Linq/Expressions/)

Comment: @L.B thanks; the Expression approach has value but I am going to instead test the output of the tests as John recommends.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your failing test *shouldn't* pass. They're not equal functions as far as anything in .NET is concerned - at least with the current Microsoft C# compiler implementation. The delegates will refer to separate generated methods (easily verified by looking at the IL.) The language specification *allows* them to be equal, but doesn't require it, and I don't know of any implementation that would do this.

Equality comparison for delegates basically consists of (for a single-action delegate):

- Do the delegates refer to the same method?
- If the delegates have targets, are those targets equal?

The first condition will be false in your test.

Comment: So by declaring the function twice, one method is generated for each which are not the same thing (uniquely named perhaps?). I can prove this by initializing a new `func` in the failing test then assigning the new `func` to `funcA` and `funcB`. The test then passes. The reason for the question is that I have some hard-coded inline `func`s that need to be verified. Would you recommend that I make these `func`s globally accessible in order to make assertions against them?

Comment: @Nick: I would test that the usage of those functions do the right thing, rather than testing that the exact same function is used.